# Bad Scanf makes the function wait/stop

Tags: c, avr

i dont know what happen  with my code, but looks like it has somethin with scanf function. 
everytime i hit the rx on function the mode 1 on function going nuts like its already have input long before i give it an input.
i dont know how to tell the detail, just ask me if theres somethin more you wanna know..

this is my code

```
//this is variable for the button function
uint8_t currentStateM1=0; //mode1
uint8_t currentStateM2=0; //txon

int main(void) {
PORTH.DIRCLR     =    PIN0_bm;
PORTH.PIN0CTRL   =    PORT_OPC_PULLUP_gc;

PORTH.DIRCLR     =    PIN1_bm;
PORTH.PIN1CTRL   =    PORT_OPC_PULLUP_gc;

while(1)
  {
     //this two is to trap an input in button because i need it to be a                    
       //switch
    //mode1
    if (!(PORTH_IN&PIN0_bm)) //check if button is pressed
    {
        onButtonM1();
        while(!(PORTH.IN&PIN0_bm)); //trap mcu until button is released
    }
    //txon
    if (!(PORTH_IN&PIN6_bm)) //check if button is pressed
    {
        onButtontxon();
        while(!(PORTH.IN&PIN6_bm)); //trap mcu until button is released
    }
   }
  }

  //===============================tx on part=============================//

    //so this is where i split the string that come in to check if the code 
    //is right or not
    //dataTXON
    char txon[12];    
    unsigned char resultxo1,resultxo2,resultxo3,resultxo4,resultxo5,resultxo6;
    int t = 0;
    char partxon[6] = {0};

    //dataInSTNDBY
    char stdby[12];    
    unsigned char      resultby1,resultby2,resultby3,resultby4,resultby5,resultby6;
    int b = 0;
    char partby[6] = {0};


   void onButtontxon(void) //call on button press
   {
     if (currentStateM2)
       {
        currentStateM2 = 0;
        _delay_ms(800);
        if ( currentStateM2 == 0)
         {
          printf("3C03BB6A02683E = STANDBY\n");
          //PORTD.DIRCLR = PIN1_bm;

            scanf("%s", &stdby);

            memcpy(partby, stdby + b, 2); b += 2;
            resultby1 = strtoul(partby, NULL, 16);
            memcpy(partby, stdby + b, 2); b += 2;
            resultby2 = strtoul(partby, NULL, 16);
            memcpy(partby, stdby + b, 2); b += 2;
            resultby3 = strtoul(partby, NULL, 16);
            memcpy(partby, stdby + b, 2); b += 2;
            resultby4 = strtoul(partby, NULL, 16);
            memcpy(partby, stdby + b, 2); b += 2;
            resultby5 = strtoul(partby, NULL, 16);
            memcpy(partby, stdby + b, 2); b += 2;
            resultby6 = strtoul(partby, NULL, 16);
            b = 0;

            int Checkstdby = resultby3^resultby4^resultby5;

            if ((resultby1 == 0x3C) && (resultby2 == 0x03) && (resultby3 ==  0xAA) && (resultby4 == 0x6A) && (resultby5 == 0x02) && (resultby6 == 0x3E) && (Checkstdby == 0xC2))
            {
                printf("awesome!\n");
                PORTE.DIRCLR = PIN3_bm;
            }    
            else if ((resultby1 != 0x3C) || (resultby2 != 0x03) || (resultby3 != 0xAA) || (resultby4 != 0x6A) || (resultby5 != 0x02) || (resultby6 != 0x3E) || (Checkstdby != 0xC2))
            {    
                printf("wrong code\n");
            }
    }
    return 0;

}

else

{
    //now this function will read if the M1 is on or not, if yes
    //this function will turn on a led to indicate that TX is ON in M1 mode 
    currentStateM2 = 1;
    _delay_ms(800);
    if (currentStateM2 == 1)
    {
        printf("3C03BB6A01D03E = TX ON");
        scanf("%s", &txon);

        memcpy(partxon, txon + t, 2); t += 2;
        resultxo1 = strtoul(partxon, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partxon, txon + t, 2); t += 2;
        resultxo2 = strtoul(partxon, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partxon, txon + t, 2); t += 2;
        resultxo3 = strtoul(partxon, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partxon, txon + t, 2); t += 2;
        resultxo4 = strtoul(partxon, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partxon, txon + t, 2); t += 2;
        resultxo5 = strtoul(partxon, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partxon, txon + t, 2); t += 2;
        resultxo6 = strtoul(partxon, NULL, 16);
        t = 0;

        int Checktx = resultxo3^resultxo4^resultxo5;

        if ((resultxo1 == 0x3C) && (resultxo2 == 0x03) && (resultxo3 == 0xAA) && (resultxo4 == 0x6A) && (resultxo5 == 0x01) && (resultxo6 == 0x3E) && (Checktx == 0xC1) && (currentStateM1 == 1))
            {
                printf("awesome!\n");
                PORTE.DIRSET = PIN3_bm;
            }                    


            else if ((resultxo1 != 0x3C) || (resultxo2 != 0x33) || (resultxo3 != 0xAA) || (resultxo4 != 0x6A) || (resultxo5 != 0x01) || (resultxo6 != 0x3E) || (Checktx != 0xC1) || (currentStateM1 != 1))
            {    
                printf("apadah\n");
            }
    }


}
}

 //===========================M1 part==============================//

    //dataIn ON
    char bc[12];    
    unsigned char result1,result2,result3,result4,result5,result6;
    int i = 0;
    char partonin[6] = {0};

    //dataIn OFF
    char bx[12];    
    unsigned char resultx1,resultx2,resultx3,resultx4,resultx5,resultx6;
    int c = 0;
    char partofin[6] = {0};

   //this is where it all begin, i push a button to trigger this function.
   //its the function to turn on/off the M1 Mode, indicated by led inside
   //the button.
   //the led inside the button turned on if the code i recieve is right
   //after mode 1 on, i want to active the TX ON funtion to it
   //back to the top....
   void onButtonM1(void) //call on button press
   {
   if (currentStateM1)

   {
    currentStateM1 = 0;
    _delay_ms(800);
    if ( currentStateM1 == 0)
    {
        printf("3C03BB6A04D53E = M1 OFF\n");
        scanf("%s", &bx);

        memcpy(partofin, bx + c, 2); c += 2;
        resultx1 = strtoul(partofin, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partofin, bx + c, 2); c += 2;
        resultx2 = strtoul(partofin, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partofin, bx + c, 2); c += 2;
        resultx3 = strtoul(partofin, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partofin, bx + c, 2); c += 2;
        resultx4 = strtoul(partofin, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partofin, bx + c, 2); c += 2;
        resultx5 = strtoul(partofin, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partofin, bx + c, 2); c += 2;
        resultx6 = strtoul(partofin, NULL, 16);
        c = 0;

        int CheckInof = resultx3^resultx4^resultx5;

        if ((resultx1 == 0x3C) && (resultx2 == 0x03) && (resultx3 == 0xAA) && (resultx4 == 0x6A) && (resultx5 == 0x04) && (resultx6 == 0x3E) && (CheckInof == 0xC4))
            {
                printf("awesome!\n");
                PORTD.DIRCLR = PIN1_bm;
            }    
            else if ((resultx1 != 0x3C) || (resultx2 != 0x03) || (resultx3 != 0xAA) || (resultx4 != 0x6A) || (resultx5 != 0x04) || (resultx6 != 0x3E) || (CheckInof != 0xC4))
            {    
                currentStateM1 = 1;
                printf("not the answer\n");
            }
    }

}

else

{
    currentStateM1 = 1;
    _delay_ms(800);
    if (currentStateM1 == 1)
    {
        printf("\n3C03BB6A03D23E = M1 ON\n");
        scanf("%s", &bc);

        memcpy(partonin, bc + i, 2); i += 2;
        result1 = strtoul(partonin, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partonin, bc + i, 2); i += 2;
        result2 = strtoul(partonin, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partonin, bc + i, 2); i += 2;
        result3 = strtoul(partonin, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partonin, bc + i, 2); i += 2;
        result4 = strtoul(partonin, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partonin, bc + i, 2); i += 2;
        result5 = strtoul(partonin, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partonin, bc + i, 2); i += 2;
        result6 = strtoul(partonin, NULL, 16);
        i = 0;

        int CheckIn = result3^result4^result5;

        if ((result1 == 0x3C) && (result2 == 0x03) && (result3 == 0xAA) && (result4 == 0x6A) && (result5 == 0x03) && (result6 == 0x3E) && (CheckIn == 0xC3))
            {
                printf("awesome!\n");
                PORTD.DIRSET = PIN1_bm;
            }    
            else if ((result1 != 0x3C) || (result2 != 0x03) || (result3 != 0xAA) || (result4 != 0x6A) || (result5 != 0x03) || (result6 != 0x3E) || (CheckIn != 0xC3))
            {    
                printf("apadah\n");
                currentStateM1 = 0;
            }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: There are more than one scanf(). Where it is going wrong and what is going wrong? Add some comments in your code. Also, remove unnecessary code if there are any.

Comment: You have added some comments, good. But please format your code. It is very difficult to read and understand. Also mention where (in which line) you are observing this issue.

Comment: done, i hope you can read it a bit more easy now. thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is your character array size is 12 and you are trying to store a string of length 12. But remember you can only store 11 characters + '\0'.

So, Change all your character array size to 13. Also make sure scanf takes only 12 characters.

```
char bc[13] = ""; //Better to initialize the array. Anyway you are doing scanf() and get the proper value. I don't see any issue.
[...]
scanf("%12s", bc); //Accept only 12 characters + '\0'.
[...]
```

2nd issue is with strtoul(). It returns `unsigned long int` value and you are storing it in `unsigned char`, which is wrong. So change

```
unsigned char resultxo1,resultxo2,resultxo3,resultxo4,resultxo5,resultxo6;
```

to

```
unsigned long int resultxo1,resultxo2,resultxo3,resultxo4,resultxo5,resultxo6;
```

3rd issue is with memcpy(). To use strtoul(), first argument has to be a string. So change

```
        memcpy(partby, stdby + b, 2); b += 2;
        resultby1 = strtoul(partby, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partby, stdby + b, 2); b += 2;
        resultby2 = strtoul(partby, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partby, stdby + b, 2); b += 2;
        resultby3 = strtoul(partby, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partby, stdby + b, 2); b += 2;
        resultby4 = strtoul(partby, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partby, stdby + b, 2); b += 2;
        resultby5 = strtoul(partby, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partby, stdby + b, 2); b += 2;
        resultby6 = strtoul(partby, NULL, 16);
        b = 0;
```

to

```
        partby[2] = '\0'; //You are copying to partby[0] and partby[1] only.
        memcpy(partby, stdby + b, 2); b += 2;
        resultby1 = strtoul(partby, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partby, stdby + b, 2); b += 2;
        resultby2 = strtoul(partby, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partby, stdby + b, 2); b += 2;
        resultby3 = strtoul(partby, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partby, stdby + b, 2); b += 2;
        resultby4 = strtoul(partby, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partby, stdby + b, 2); b += 2;
        resultby5 = strtoul(partby, NULL, 16);
        memcpy(partby, stdby + b, 2); b += 2;
        resultby6 = strtoul(partby, NULL, 16);
        b = 0;
```

You need to make all these changes for all the arrays and result variables.